# Can I address a repeated property or a structured property using a ndb.key

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I tried to address a repeated property element using a key, like : ndb.Key('Books', 'Programming.one') but this key (the .one part) is not valid.

My example model below is a simplified version of my app's model. In this example code I have dependencies (using keys) between book chapters and tags :

```
class Tags(ndb.Model):
    tag = ndb.StringProperty()
```

example : Tags(id = 'python', tag = 'python')

```
class Books(ndb.Model):
    book = ndb.StringProperty)
    chapters = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
```

example : Books(id = 'Programming', book = 'Programming', chapters = ['one', 'two'])

```
class Dependencies(ndb.Model):
    chapter_key = ndb.KeyProperty()
    tag_keys = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated = True)
```

example :

```
chapter_key = ndb.Key('Books','Programming.one')
dependency_key = ndb.Key('Dependencies', chapter_key.id())
Dependencies(key = dependency_key, chapter_key = chapter_key, 
                   tag_keys = [ndb.Key('Tags', 'python'), ndb.Key('Tags', 'java')])
```

Is it possible to address a repeated property using a ndb.Key. In my code example the chapter_key is not valid. Can I use a hook or property subclass to make it work?

To make it work I can combine a valid Book Key with a StringProperty to hold the chapter.

```
book_key = ndb.Key('Books','Programming')
chapter = 'one'
dependency_key = ndb.Key('Dependencies', book_key.id() + '.' + chapter)
Dependencies(key = dependency_key, book_key = book_key, chapter = chapter, 
                   tag_keys = [ndb.Key('Tags', 'python'), ndb.Key('Tags', 'java')])
```

But I would like to benifit from a key.

I have the same question for a structured property. For this question the repeated StringProperty chapters is replaced by a repeated StructuredProperty like :

```
class Chapters(ndb.Model):
    chapter = ndb.StringProperty()
    word_count = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

About my example and the use of keys :

I use keys in Dependencies, because keys in dependencies can refer to different kinds. These kinds differ from the Book like kind, because they do not have a repeated property like Book chapters. I use repeated depends_on_keys in my application, instead of chapter_keys.

In the example I also left out the parent keys. The Book like kind can have dependencies, but in my application you cannot find entities, which depend on the Book like kind.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace? All this stuff should work.

Comment: The error occurs when I press the owner_key in the datastore viewer.  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9-mEcXX8BPaWW9uc3FVaExwdHM/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use a key to identify a part of an entity. If you want to reference a part of an entity, you will need to use a key in conjunction with your own scheme for addressing entity parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious because the code above dont seem right in sintax terms:

```
tag_keys = [ndb.Key('Tags', 'python', ndb.Key('Tags', 'java']
```

You can use the code bellow, it worked for me:

```
class SomeModel(ndb.Model):
    pass


class WithKeys(ndb.Model):
    keys=ndb.KeyProperty(SomeModel,repeated=True)

keys=[ndb.Key(SomeModel,i) for i in range(1,10)]

with_keys=WithKeys(keys=keys)

print with_keys.keys
```

It prints:

```
[Key('SomeModel', 1), Key('SomeModel', 2), Key('SomeModel', 3), Key('SomeModel', 4), Key('SomeModel', 5), Key('SomeModel', 6), Key('SomeModel', 7), Key('SomeModel', 8), Key('SomeModel', 9)]
```

Goog luck

Comment: I forgot to type some closing parenthesis in the example, Thanks. I do not use the kind argument in the KeyProperty, because in my app the keys can reference different kinds.

Comment: If you remove the kind, it will work the same way and you will be able to assign any key to you property. I hope it helped you.